# adding css dynamically in jquery

Tags: jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#submit").click(function(){


         var userinput = $('#username').val();
         var mobilenumber=$('#mobnum').val();
         var address1=$('#addr1').val();
         var address2=$('#addr2').val();

         var characterReg = /^([a-zA-Z]{2,30})$/;
         var numericReg=/^\d*[0-9](|.\d*[0-9]|,\d*[0-9])?$/;
         var emailReg=/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
         var addrReg = /^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9,\s]+\s*$/;

         var errors=false;

        if(!characterReg.test(userinput)){
             $('#username').addClass('box alert');
            errors=true;
        }else{
            $('#username').removeClass('box alert');
        }
        if(!numericReg.test(mobilenumber)){
            $('#mobnum').addClass('box alert');
            errors=true;
        }else{
            $('#mobnum').removeClass('box alert');
        }
        if($('#mail').val()==''){
            $('#mail').addClass('box alert');
            errors=true;
        }else{
            $('#mail').removeClass('box alert');
        }
        if($('#pwd').val()==''){
            $('#pwd').addClass('box alert');
            errors=true;    
        }else{
            $('#pwd').removeClass('box alert');
        }
        if(!addrReg.test(address1)){
            $('#addr1').addClass('box alert');
            errors=true;
        }else{
            $('#addr1').removeClass('box alert');
        }
        if(!characterReg.test(address2)){
            $('#addr2').addClass('box alert');
            errors=true;    
        }else{
            $('#addr2').removeClass('box alert');
        }
        if(errors){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }); 
});
```

```css
.box{
            border-color: red;
        }
        .alert{
            color:#a94442;
            background-color: #f2dede;
            border:#ebccd1;
            opacity: 1;
            padding:10px;
        }
        form{
            margin-top:20px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
<div class="alert">
    "Missing required field"
</div>
 <form method="post" id="user_form">

        NAME <br>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="req" ><br>
        MOBILE NUMBER <br>
        <input type="text" name="mobnum" id="mobnum" class="req" maxlength="10"><br>
        E-MAIL <br>
        <input type="email" name="mail" id="mail" class="req" ><br>    
        PASSWORD <br>
        <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" class="req" ><br>    
        ADDRESS 1<br>
        <input type="text" name="addr1" id="addr1" class="req" ><br>
        ADDRESS 2<br>
        <input type="text" name="addr2" id="addr2" class="req" ><br>
        <button type="submit"  id="submit">Submit</button>

 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

i wrote this code for form validation..here if i click submit without entering any values it should show text box color and "missing required field" at top of the page .. i added code for that.. but when i click submit without entering values .."alert" class should apply for only div ..not for text box.. is my code correct?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking here.

Comment: when i click submit with no values.. text box color must be changed.. and at top of the page i should display the error message..after entering values i want to hide it

Comment: you mean without pressing submit button you want to hide those error color on fields ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code go through with below link may be this can help you to resolve your error-

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zg73n5t7/35/)

HTML Code:

```
<div class="alert">
  "Missing required field"
</div>
<form method="post" id="user_form">

  NAME
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="req">
  <br> MOBILE NUMBER
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="mobnum" id="mobnum" class="req" maxlength="10">
  <br> E-MAIL
  <br>
  <input type="email" name="mail" id="mail" class="req">
  <br> PASSWORD
  <br>
  <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" class="req">
  <br> ADDRESS 1
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="addr1" id="addr1" class="req">
  <br> ADDRESS 2
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="addr2" id="addr2" class="req">
  <br>
  <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

CSS Code:

```
.box {
  border-color: red;
}

.alert {
  color: #a94442;
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border: #ebccd1;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}

form {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('div.alert').hide();


$("#submit").click(function() {
    $('input.alert').removeClass('alert box');
    var userinput = $('#username').val();
    var mobilenumber = $('#mobnum').val();
    var address1 = $('#addr1').val();
    var address2 = $('#addr2').val();
    var characterReg = /^([a-zA-Z]{2,30})$/;
    var numericReg = /^\d*[0-9](|.\d*[0-9]|,\d*[0-9])?$/;
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    var addrReg = /^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9,\s]+\s*$/;

    var errors = false;

    if (!characterReg.test(userinput)) {
      $('#username').addClass('box alert');
      $('#username').focus();
      $('div.alert').text('Missing required field - *Name*');
      $('div.alert').show();
      errors = true;
    } else {
      $('#username').removeClass('box alert');
    }
    if (errors == false && !numericReg.test(mobilenumber)) {
      $('#mobnum').addClass('box alert');
      $('#mobnum').focus();
      $('div.alert').text('Missing required field - *Mobile Number*');
      $('div.alert').show();
      errors = true;
    } else {
      $('#mobnum').removeClass('box alert');
    }
    if (errors == false && $('#mail').val() == '') {
      $('#mail').addClass('box alert');
      $('#mail').focus();
      $('div.alert').text('Missing required field - *E-Mail*');
      $('div.alert').show();
      errors = true;
    } else {
      $('#mail').removeClass('box alert');
    }
    if (errors == false && $('#pwd').val() == '') {
      $('#pwd').addClass('box alert');
      $('#pwd').focus();
      $('div.alert').text('Missing required field - *Password*');
      $('div.alert').show();
      errors = true;
    } else {
      $('#pwd').removeClass('box alert');
    }
    if (errors == false && !addrReg.test(address1)) {
      $('#addr1').addClass('box alert');
      $('#addr1').focus();
      $('div.alert').text('Missing required field - *Address Line 1*');
      $('div.alert').show();
      errors = true;
    } else {
      $('#addr1').removeClass('box alert');
    }
    if (errors == false && !characterReg.test(address2)) {
      $('#addr2').addClass('box alert');
      $('#addr2').focus();
      $('div.alert').text('Missing required field - *Address Line 2*');
      $('div.alert').show();
      errors = true;
    } else {
      $('#addr2').removeClass('box alert');
    }
    if (errors) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: its working..but can i apply style only for error message?

Comment: @moksha What type of style you want on error message?

Comment: @moksha I can just modified my fiddle link and answer also please go through that it can now gives you a new error message whenever any input field going to empty.

Comment: i have added alert class right?.. that class should display only for error messaage ... not to that text box..

Comment: My pleasure :) @moksha

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event on input to remove class after entering values like this

```
 $('#user_form > input').each(function(){
    $(this).keypress(function(){
     $(this).removeClass('box alert')
    }
 );})
```

Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/9980/)